# setting up subdomains on nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have 2 application installed on my server using Nginx:

1. Rails application
2. wordpress blog

I want that the rails app will be accessible through: staging.mydomain.com and that the wordpress blog will be accessible through: blog.mydomain.com

the site works fine but when i try to access the blog i get "welcome to nginx" screen.

here is my nginx config:

```
server {
     listen   80;
     server_name staging.mydomain.com;
     rails_env staging;

     access_log /srv/www/staging/www/logs/access.log;
     error_log /srv/www/staging/www/logs/error.log;

     location / {
          root   /srv/www/staging/www/current/trunk/web/public;
          passenger_enabled on;
          }

   }
   server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  blog.mydomain.com;


        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        access_log /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com/logs/access.log;
        error_log /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com/logs/error.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   localhost:53217;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        }
    }
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have anything configured for `location /` for the blog server, which means that if a URL doesn't end in `.php`, it uses the nginx's default document root.

Comment: so how do i add th `location /` so it wont collide with the other subdomain?

Comment: Each `server { } ` section should have its own `location / { }` clause. They won't conflict.

Comment: so the blog should have `location / { root /srv/www/blog.mydomain.com;}` ?

Comment: @Ran: Looks about right.